# MYSQL update rows by inner select

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use inner joins to get an old password and a new password and then enter the old password into customer_entity table. Currently i have this script

```
select ce.email, ce.entity_id, ce.password_hash new_password, p.password_hash old_password from b2b_needsmigrating b2b
inner join customer_entity ce on ce.email = b2b.email
left join b2b_backup_passwords p on p.email = b2b.email
where ce.website_id = 1
and ce.entity_id < 2693
order by ce.entity_id
```

It gives me the result :
[image]

How can i write it in an update statement so customer_entity replaces 'ce.password_hash' with 'old_password'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, because emails with entity_id should be unique, but you can add more columns to the on clause

```
UPDATE customer_entity ce1
INNER JOIN
(select ce.email, ce.entity_id, ce.password_hash new_password, p.password_hash old_password 
from b2b_needsmigrating b2b
inner join customer_entity ce on ce.email = b2b.email
left join b2b_backup_passwords p on p.email = b2b.email
where ce.website_id = 1
and ce.entity_id < 2693) t1 ON t1.email = ce1.email AND t1.entity_id = ce1.entity_id
 SET ce1.password_hash = t1.old_password
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
UPDATE customer_entity cust
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ce.email, ce.entity_id, ce.password_hash new_password, p.password_hash old_password 
    FROM b2b_needsmigrating b2b
    INNER JOIN customer_entity ce ON ce.email = b2b.email
    LEFT JOIN b2b_backup_passwords p ON p.email = b2b.email
    WHERE ce.website_id = 1
    AND ce.entity_id < 2693
    ORDER by ce.entity_id
) AS res ON res.email = cust.email AND res.entity_id = cust.entity_id
SET cust.password_hash = res.new_password
```

Comment: a little late and brings nothing new to the question

Comment: Brings aliasing and formatting to the question. @nbk

Comment: it is still a duplicate

Comment: Don't think that would matter. Everyone or Anyone can contribute their own answers on stack overflow. Not really sure what is bothering you. I was formatting the SQL before you posted the answer.